# Using a vim syntax file, I would like some Keywords, such as ??, to be colored

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, syntax-highlighting, terminal, colorscheme

I have been trying to get through the syntax file documentation on vim help, 
https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-files

 but it's quite the read and I figured someone here may know how to go about what I'm trying to do.

---

I do most of my note taking in vim. I have made a simple syntax file for better organizing my thoughts but I'm looking to expand it as I only get two colors at the moment. This is my current file:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")     
  finish                          
endif                             
                                  
syn match keywordObject "=="      
syn match keywordObject "\["      
syn match keywordObject "\]"      
syn match keywordObject "]=="     
syn match keywordIfFalse "=="     
syn match keywordIfTrue "::"      
syn match keyworActor "--"     

syn match keywordAs "*"    
syn match comment "#.*$"          
                                  
let b:current_syntax = "notes"    
                                  
hi def link keywordObject Keyword 
hi def link keywordIfFalse Keyword
hi def link keywordIfTrue Keyword 
hi def link keywordActor Keyword  
hi def link keywordAs Keyword     
hi def link comment Keyword
```

This lets me organize my thoughts better as I use Lines of ==, --, or :: to divide my notes into sections. Bullet points *, are also colored.

I would like to squeeze some additional functionality out of this, and also get more color as everything but the comments are the same yellow color.

Ideally:

```
!! Text surrounded by exclamation marks colored bright red to mark importance !!
?? Text surrounded by question marks colored bright pink to mark questions ??

//
Text encased by slashes as light green to mark a misc
idea that's interesting and loosely relevant, but can
be ignored if reading notes for review
\\

* Bullet points (just the bullet not the following text) as
  light yellow to further be distinguished
```

But I am not too picky about what the colors are if there is a limitation, I would just like a bit more variety. Thanks to any help. I would like this to be achieved through just a .vim syntax file and without any plugins.

Comment: You might want regions for the first two

Comment: Could I have an example of a functional region?

Comment: I've done something similar for help files I've written. Can't give you the `_vimrc` mapping but the following syntax highlights text wrapped in `!` `syntax match myIgnoreHs /!/ contained conceal` 
`syn match myhelpvSpecial        "!.*!"   contains=myIgnoreHs`
`hi def link myhelpvSpecial  mySpecial`
The followig assigns the colour
`SynColor myspecial  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=Black  gui=NONE guifg=#000000 guibg=LightYellow`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples. (Note that your `keywordAs` already covers the bullet, you just need to highlight it as you want.)

When the delimiters are always on the same line, this is probably the simplest way to go:

```
syntax match Important /!!.*!!/
```

But to be more flexible, allowing delimiters anywhere, use a region:

```
" Don't use Question; it's a `:help highlight-default`
syntax region MyQuestion start='??' end='??'
syntax region Misc start='//' end='\\\\'
```

Then add some highlights. You can link to groups that already have colors you like (see `:help highlight-default` and `:help group-name`), or just make your own:

```
highlight def link Important Error
highlight def MyQuestion ctermfg=magenta
highlight def Misc ctermfg=green
```

Note that these don't overlap by default. If you need to nest them, have a look at `contains`.